# Trouble getting HMACsha256 to produce expected results

Tags: rest, go, encryption, hmac, sha

I'm trying to hook into the Binance API and have discovered that my implementation of HMACsha256 isn't producing the results that the sample documentation (and doing it in the command line) can. I'm trying to improve my knowledge of Go, but can't seem to crack this one.

Here's the documentation (Relevant Sample at "SIGNED Endpoint Examples for POST /api/v1/order"): https://github.com/binance-exchange/binance-official-api-docs/blob/master/rest-api.md

Without looking at the doc, here is the gist, my key is the following:

```
NhqPtmdSJYdKjVHjA7PZj4Mge3R5YNiP1e3UZjInClVN65XAbvqqM6A7H5fATj0j
```

my value is the following:

```
symbol=LTCBTC&side=BUY&type=LIMIT&timeInForce=GTC&quantity=1&price=0.1&recvWindow=5000&timestamp=1499827319559
```

When I use the terminal with the following command:

```
echo -n "symbol=LTCBTC&side=BUY&type=LIMIT&timeInForce=GTC&quantity=1&price=0.1&recvWindow=5000&timestamp=1499827319559" | openssl dgst -sha256 -hmac "NhqPtmdSJYdKjVHjA7PZj4Mge3R5YNiP1e3UZjInClVN65XAbvqqM6A7H5fATj0j"
```

I receive the result

```
c8db56825ae71d6d79447849e617115f4a920fa2acdcab2b053c4b2838bd6b71
```

Which is what the documentation suggests. But when I use the following go program:

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/hmac"
    "crypto/sha256"
    "encoding/base64"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    docSecret := "NhqPtmdSJYdKjVHjA7PZj4Mge3R5YNiP1e3UZjInClVN65XAbvqqM6A7H5fATj0j"
    docQuery := "symbol=LTCBTC&side=BUY&type=LIMIT&timeInForce=GTC&quantity=1&price=0.1&recvWindow=5000&timestamp=1499827319559"
    result := hmacify(docQuery, docSecret)
    fmt.Println(result)
}

func hmacify(message string, secret string) string {
    key := []byte(secret)
    h := hmac.New(sha256.New, key)
    h.Write([]byte(message))
    return base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(h.Sum(nil))
}
```

produces the result:

```
yNtWglrnHW15RHhJ5hcRX0qSD6Ks3KsrBTxLKDi9a3E=
```

What am I misunderstanding that's causing such a massive difference from the sample and command line?

Comment: The output from the docs is displayed in hex, but you are displaying your output in base64. Try the `encoding/hex` package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got the same result in both cases. It's just encoded differently. The `openssl` command encodes it as hex and your function uses `base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString()` to encode it as base64.

Here's a small Python 2 snippet showing this:

```
>>> x = "c8db56825ae71d6d79447849e617115f4a920fa2acdcab2b053c4b2838bd6b71"
>>> y = "yNtWglrnHW15RHhJ5hcRX0qSD6Ks3KsrBTxLKDi9a3E=".decode('base64').encode('hex')
>>> y
'c8db56825ae71d6d79447849e617115f4a920fa2acdcab2b053c4b2838bd6b71'
>>> x == y
True
```

To get the exact same result as the command line use `hex.EncodeToString()` as @Anuruddha suggested.

```
import "encoding/hex"

func hmacify(message string, secret string) string {
    key := []byte(secret)
    h := hmac.New(sha256.New, key)
    h.Write([]byte(message))
    return hex.EncodeToString(h.Sum(nil))  // <--- change is HERE
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Result is displayed in hex not in base64. Here is the [play ground](https://play.golang.org/p/EszhPA2H46Q) link to the modified code